# Java - EnumSet.noneOf()- Why use Class<E> instead of T?

Tags: java, android, oop, generics, reflection

The definition is:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/EnumSet

```
noneOf(Class<E> elementType)
Creates an empty enum set with the specified element type.
```

But why does it require `Class<E>` and not, say, T as in `noneOf(T elementType)` ?
Is it because it requires the type to be entered at runtime?
But when I write code for example `EnumSet.noneOf(Authority.class);` I know the type (Authority) at compile time,so could it have been `EnumSet.noneOf(Authority)` ?

Since it seems to require  though,why not use the anytype as in Class<?>

Comment: because it needs a `Class`, to specify the `enum` and not just an instance of that  `enum` (you could not use the method for an empty `enum` {why ever one is declared empty} nor does it make much sense {what is the exact meaning of using the one constant instead of another one})

Comment: `EnumSet.noneOf(Authority)` is not legal Java.  If you want to pass a type in Java, you use a class literal (i.e., `Authority.class`). And it doesn't make sense to pass an _instance_ of a type when you want an empty set of said type. Also, if it used `Class<?>` then you could pass _any_ type, not just an enum type. Though that can be solved with an upper bound. But with a wildcard, you can't get an `EnumSet<E>` back.; it would be an `EnumSet<?>` , which is not exactly useful.

Comment: Note that `E` is bounded (the declaration is `<E extends Enum<E>>`).

Comment: @Slaw I suggest you make an Answer of your useful Comments.

Comment: @Slaw please add your comment as an answer so I pick it.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know the type (Authority) at compile time,so could it have been `EnumSet.noneOf(Authority)` ?

You can't do `EnumSet.noneOf(Authority)` because that's not legal Java. When you want to pass around a type then you use a `Class` instance, and when you know the needed class at compile-time, you use a class literal (e.g., `Authority.class`).

---

> But why does it require `Class<E>` and not, say, T as in `noneOf(T elementType)` ?

Conceptually, it makes no sense to require an *instance* of a type when you want an *empty* set of said type. But then I suppose the question becomes, "Why is any argument needed in the first place?". After all, you can do something like:

```java
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
```

Without passing a `Class` instance.

The reason is because `EnumSet` is a highly specialized `Set` implementation. It needs to know of all the existing `enum` constants, which can be queried using the `Class`, even when the set is empty. Also, the implementation only works with a *single type*. An `EnumSet` cannot contain constants from different `enum` types. The `Class` allows the implementation to enforce this.

Other methods, such as `EnumSet#of(E)`, don't require a `Class` because they require instances of the `enum` (i.e., one or more constants) and the type can be grabbed from them.

---

> Since it seems to require though,why not use the anytype as in Class<?>

Because a `Class<?>` would allow you to pass *any type*, not just an `enum` type. Though of course that could be solved by bounding the wildcard: `Class<? extends Enum<?>>`. Now only `enum` types are allowed, but the static type system has no idea *which* `enum` type you're using. This means methods such as `noneOf` would only be capable of returning an `EnumSet<?>`, which is not very useful.

By declaring a type variable `E` and bounding it to extend `Enum<E>`, the use of `Class<E>` forces you to pass an `enum` type *and* you get an `EnumSet<E>` back.

Comment: It is legal Java but it doesn't agree with the method signature of the method being used. Not the same thing.

Comment: `EnumSet.noneOf(Authority)` is _not_ legal Java. Note that `Authority` is not a variable name, it's a **class** name.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers don't seem to give charitable interpretations of your question, so I'll add one.

> But why does it require Class and not, say, T as in noneOf(T elementType) ?

It's because the EnumSet needs to be able to verify the type later.  For example:

```java
var set = EnumSet.noneOf(Authority.class);
set.add(Authority.ADMIN); // ordinal 1
```

On the second line, the set needs to verify that enum being added to the set is the same type as the others.  There wouldn't be a way to check the types match if someone later wrote:

```java
set.add(Color.BLUE) // ordinal 1, oops!
```

It wouldn't be possible to distinguish the problem without the enum class. You ask a valid question of why this should be the type with (lightly rewritten):

> EnumSet.noneOf(Authority.ADMIN)

This would be possible, except it wouldn't work for empty enums:

```java
enum Empty {}
```

Finally, it's important to note the values from each enum may have different classes:

```java
enum Authority {
  ADMIN {
    @Override void checkPermissions() {...}
  },
  USER {
    @Override void checkPermissions() {...}
  };

  abstract void checkPermissions();
}
assert Authority.ADMIN.getClass() != Authority.USER.getClass();
```

As a result, the *outermost* class needs to be passed into `EnumSet`, so the class object is preferred.

Comment: `EnumSet` doesn't do any verification. The compiler does it, via the `Class<E>` provided by the caller. That ensures that you get an `EnumSet<E>`, and the rest follows by the rules of Java. I don't know what you mean by 'charitable'.

Comment: @user207421 I agree that in the case above, the verification would be done by the compiler. However, the `EnumSet` implementations do a type check at run-time. You can see this in the implementation, or by creating a **raw** `EnumSet` for one type and then trying to add a different type. It's not strictly spelled out that a `ClassCastException` will be thrown in that situation, but that behavior is reasonably inferred from the documentation of `Set` and `EnumSet`.

Comment: @user207421:  The code does type check (necessary for serialization too).  Both OpenJDK and Apache Harmony check it.  The original answer is not charitable because 
"EnumSet.noneOf(Authority) is not legal Java. " While technically true, I think it's clear the user meant passing an element of the enum, not literally that text.